# Laravel - Get Pivot Table Relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, relationship

I have four tables: characters, pets, characters_pets and characters_pets_metadata.
A character has many pets on the pivot table characters_pets, but I also need to get the data from the metadata table:

```
class Character extends Model {

    protected $table = 'characters';

    public function pets() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Pet', 'characters_pets');
    }
}



class CharacterPet extends Model {

    protected $table = 'characters_pets';

    public function metadata() {
        return $this->hasMany('PetMetadata');
    }

}
```

How can I fetch the metadata for each character pet through a relationship?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you looking for something like:

```
$character = Character::find(1);

foreach($character->pets as $pet){

    // you can access any pet information here

    foreach($pet->metadata as $meta){

       var_dump($meta); // your meta information here

    }

}
```

Comment: Won't this produce N+1 query problem @ariful-haque? How can we avoid it?